# How to put a custom overlay on Clappr video player when I’m fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to put an overlay on top of my video player when viewing in fullscreen.
My initial idea is to append my overlay element on the Clappr.core.$el somewhere whenever the player goes into fullscreen by listening to the fullscreen event. I haven’t been successful with that yet.

Is there a way to listen to the fullscreen event and prevent default somehow and the call fullscreen on another element that has both the overlay and the video player as children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a red overlay to the video when in fullscreen mode. To do this i targetted the `fullscreen` class that gets applied to the parent div of the `video` tag. here is a jsfiddle link to give a brief idea https://jsfiddle.net/hdug6mfc/